# How to change the manipulation of the point Q to a Locator?

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, scripting, education

I want to control the point Q by a `Locator` not with `Slider`, how to make this work?

```
    Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{Q, AB, angle, normAB , ThreePoints, fa, v1, v2, r},
  AB = OB - OA;
  normAB = If[Norm[AB] != 0, Norm[AB], 1];
  
  Q = OA + t AB;
  
  ThreePoints = {OP, Q, OA};
  v1 = ThreePoints[[1]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  v2 = ThreePoints[[3]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  fa[rd_List] := Arg[rd[[1]] + I rd[[2]]];
  angle = 
   If[fa[v2] > fa[v1], {fa[v1], fa[v2]}, {fa[v1], 2 Pi + fa[v2]}];
  If[angle[[2]] - angle[[1]] >= Pi, 
   angle = {angle[[2]], angle[[1]] + 2 Pi}];
  r = Min[Norm[v1], Norm[v2]]/3;
  
  Graphics[
   {Purple, PointSize[0.03], Point[Q],
    {Thickness[0.003], Black, InfiniteLine[{OA, OB}]},
    {Thickness[0.003], Black, Line[{Q, OP}]},
    Text[Style["A", 13], OA + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB],
    Text[Style["B", 13], OB + 0.5 ( {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB],
    Text[Style["Q", FontSize -> 16, Purple], 
     Q + 0.5 ( {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB],
    Text[Style["P", FontSize -> 16, Purple], OP + 0.3 {1, 1}],
    Text[Style["drag the point Q until PQ makes an right 
angle with the line", FontSize -> 18, Black], {6, 6}],
    
    (* Plot circle and arrows for the angle *)
    RGBColor[.49, 0, 0], Circle[ThreePoints[[2]], r, angle], 
    Arrowheads[Medium],
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[2]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[2]]]},
      {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[2]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[2]] + 0.0025]}}], 
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[1]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[1]] + 0.0025]},
      {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[1]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[1]]]}}],
    
    (*plot the value of the angle*)
    Text[
     Style[NumberForm[
       N[(angle[[2]] - angle[[1]])/Pi*180] "°", {5, 2}], Bold, 14],
     {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 1.5* r Cos[Mean[angle]], 
      ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 1.5* r Sin[Mean[angle]]}]
    },
   Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Blue, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-4, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
  ],
 
 {{OA, {8, -1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{OB, {2, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{OP, {6, 4}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{t, 0.5, Style["Q", Bold, Purple, 18]}, -3, 3, 0.01, Slider}
 ]
```

This is the graph right now, How to control point Q by a `Locator`? Like the other points?
I'm new to Mathematica, And I have tried many things but none worked!
thanks for helping!
[image: the graph]

Answer (score 4):

Declare Q to be a locator and add a statement that forces Q to be on the line A to B and delete Q from the list of local variables.

Here is the changed code:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{AB, angle, normAB, ThreePoints, fa, v1, v2, r}, 
  AB = OB - OA;
  normAB = If[Norm[AB] != 0, Norm[AB], 1];
  (*Q=OA+t AB;*)
  Q = OA + ((Q - OA) . AB/normAB)  AB/normAB;
  ThreePoints = {OP, Q, OA};
  v1 = ThreePoints[[1]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  v2 = ThreePoints[[3]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  fa[rd_List] := Arg[rd[[1]] + I rd[[2]]];
  angle = 
   If[fa[v2] > fa[v1], {fa[v1], fa[v2]}, {fa[v1], 2 Pi + fa[v2]}];
  If[angle[[2]] - angle[[1]] >= Pi, 
   angle = {angle[[2]], angle[[1]] + 2 Pi}];
  r = Min[Norm[v1], Norm[v2]]/3;
  Graphics[{Purple, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[Q], {Thickness[0.003], Black, 
     InfiniteLine[{OA, OB}]}, {Thickness[0.003], Black, 
     Line[{Q, OP}]}, 
    Text[Style["A", 13], OA + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["B", 13], OB + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["Q", FontSize -> 16, Purple], 
     Q + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["P", FontSize -> 16, Purple], OP + 0.3 {1, 1}], 
    Text[Style["drag the point Q until PQ makes an right 
angle with the line", FontSize -> 18, Black], {6, 
      6}],(*Plot circle and arrows for the angle*)RGBColor[.49, 0, 0],
     Circle[ThreePoints[[2]], r, angle], Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[2]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[2]]]}, {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 
        r Cos[angle[[2]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[2]] + 0.0025]}}], 
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[1]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[1]] + 0.0025]}, {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 
        r Cos[angle[[1]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[1]]]}}],(*plot the value of the angle*)
    Text[Style[
      NumberForm[N[(angle[[2]] - angle[[1]])/Pi*180] "°", {5, 2}], 
      Bold, 14], {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 1.5*r Cos[Mean[angle]], 
      ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 1.5*r Sin[Mean[angle]]}]}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Blue, Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]},
    GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-4, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]], {{OA, {8, -1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, 
  Locator}, {{OB, {2, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, 
  Locator}, {{OP, {6, 4}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10

}, Locator},
 {{Q, {4, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the answer and this is working! but I don't understand this line of code where Q = OA + ((Q - OA) . AB/normAB) AB/normAB;               how you can put Q in the right side of the equation when its not declared yet?

Comment: It is already declared and has a value by: {{Q, {4, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator}

Answer (score 2):

This seems a trivial fix.  Not certain if you have have a larger question.

Essentially, just change:

```
{{t, 0.5, Style["Q", Bold, Purple, 18]}, -3, 3, 0.01, Slider}
```

to

```
{{t, 0.5, Style["Q", Bold, Purple, 18]}, -3, 3, 0.01, Locator}
```

More completely...

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{Q, AB, angle, normAB, ThreePoints, fa, v1, v2, r}, 
  AB = OB - OA;
  normAB = If[Norm[AB] != 0, Norm[AB], 1];
  Q = OA + t AB;
  ThreePoints = {OP, Q, OA};
  v1 = ThreePoints[[1]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  v2 = ThreePoints[[3]] - ThreePoints[[2]];
  fa[rd_List] := Arg[rd[[1]] + I rd[[2]]];
  angle = 
   If[fa[v2] > fa[v1], {fa[v1], fa[v2]}, {fa[v1], 2 Pi + fa[v2]}];
  If[angle[[2]] - angle[[1]] >= Pi, 
   angle = {angle[[2]], angle[[1]] + 2 Pi}];
  r = Min[Norm[v1], Norm[v2]]/3;
  Graphics[{Purple, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[Q], {Thickness[0.003], Black, 
     InfiniteLine[{OA, OB}]}, {Thickness[0.003], Black, 
     Line[{Q, OP}]}, 
    Text[Style["A", 13], OA + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["B", 13], OB + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["Q", FontSize -> 16, Purple], 
     Q + 0.5 ({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . AB)/normAB], 
    Text[Style["P", FontSize -> 16, Purple], OP + 0.3 {1, 1}], 
    Text[Style["drag the point Q until PQ makes an right 
angle with the line", FontSize -> 18, Black], {6, 
      6}],(*Plot circle and arrows for the angle*)RGBColor[.49, 0, 0],
     Circle[ThreePoints[[2]], r, angle], Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[2]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[2]]]}, {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 
        r Cos[angle[[2]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + r Sin[angle[[2]] + 0.0025]}}], 
    Arrow[{{ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + r Cos[angle[[1]] + 0.0025], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[1]] + 0.0025]}, {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 
        r Cos[angle[[1]]], 
       ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 
        r Sin[angle[[1]]]}}],(*plot the value of the angle*)
    Text[
     Style[
      NumberForm[
       N[(angle[[2]] - angle[[1]])/Pi*180] "\[Degree]", {5, 2}], Bold,
       14], {ThreePoints[[2, 1]] + 1.5*r Cos[Mean[angle]], 
      ThreePoints[[2, 2]] + 1.5*r Sin[Mean[angle]]}]}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Blue, Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]},
    GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-4, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]],
 {{OA, {8, -1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{OB, {2, 2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{OP, {6, 4}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 {{t, 0.5, Style["Q", Bold, Purple, 18]}, -3, 3, 0.01, Locator}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work !